# MERGE / UPDATE Query for ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two different tables, table1 and table2 as shown below

table1

| LA_ID | ADDRESS | CITY | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 572 | A1 | C1 | S1 |
| 300 | A1 | C1 | S1 |
| 978 | A1 | C1 | S1 |
| 082 | A2 | C2 | S2 |
| 026 | A2 | C2 | S2 |
| 093 | A2 | C2 | S2 |

table2

| LA_ID |
| --- |
| 572 |
| 572 |
| 300 |
| 300 |
| 978 |
| 978 |
| 978 |
| 978 |
| 082 |
| 082 |
| 082 |
| 026 |
| 026 |
| 093 |

I want to update the table2 LA_ID to look like

| LA_ID |
| --- |
| 572 |
| 572 |
| 572 |
| 572 |
| 572 |
| 572 |
| 572 |
| 572 |
| 082 |
| 082 |
| 082 |
| 082 |
| 082 |
| 082 |

basically updating the LA_ID of table2 to the LA_ID of table1, where ADDRESS, CITY and state are same.

I tried this

```
SET LA_ID = (SELECT new_LA_ID from (
(Select min(LA_ID) over
(partition by ADDRESS, city, state) as new_LA_ID,
LA_ID old_LA_ID
from table2 )) src
where src.old_LA_ID = tgt.LA_ID )
where tgt.LA_ID in (Select LA_ID old_LA_ID
from table2 
);
```

Comment: Why 572 and not 300 or 978?

Comment: It can be any of these. I tried min(LA_ID) so it was updating with the LA_ID of first_row which here is 572 and 082

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use just the minimum or maximum value, you can simply use `update`:

```
update table_2 t2
    set la_id = (select min(t1.la_id)
                 from table_1 t1 join
                      table_1 t12
                      on t1.state = t12.state and t1.city = t12.city and t1.address = t12.address
                 where t12.la_id = t2.la_id
                )
    where la_id <> (select min(t1.la_id)
                    from table_1 t1 join
                         table_1 t12
                         on t1.state = t12.state and t1.city = t12.city and t1.address = t12.address
                    where t12.la_id = t2.la_id
                   );
```

I'm not sure how you are choosing `572` and `082` for the specific ids you want when there are duplicates.  This would choose `300` and `026`.

Comment: the thing is the table2 which you have used as t2 has only one column LA_ID so it can not be matched to state, city, address of t1

Comment: Can you please explain the table_1 t12 join part

Comment: @RishuTripathi . . . That purpose of the subquery is to get the lowest id on the address that matches the outer id.  This uses a self-join.  I'm not sure if there is another method in Oracle.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff ! This was very helpful.